# why dynamic allocation use more RAM?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

While solving the longest palindromic substring problem on LeetCode, I found that in my 2 identical solution, the one which use dynamic allocation use up to 244 MB of RAM, while the other only use 10 MB of RAM.

Static allocation solution (dynamic solution in the comment section on the code)

```
char * longestPalindrome(char * s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    int ps[n][n]; //int *ps = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(ps[0][0]) * n * n);
    int maxi = 0, maxj = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ps[i][i] = 1; //ps[i*n+i] = 1;
    }
    for (int l = 2; l <= n; l++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - l; i++)
        {
            int j = i + l - 1;
            if (i == j - 1)
            {
                if (ps[i][j] = (s[i] == s[j])) //if (ps[i*n+j] = (s[i] == s[j]))
                {
                    maxi = i;
                    maxj = j;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ps[i][j] = (s[i] == s[j] && ps[i + 1][j - 1])) //if (ps[i*n+j] = (s[i] == s[j] && ps[(i + 1)*n+(j - 1)]))
                {
                    maxi = i;
                    maxj = j;
                }
            }
        }
    } //free(ps)
    char *p = &s[maxi];
    s[maxj + 1] = '\0';
    return p;
}
```

Comment: `int ps[n][n];` is somewhat likely to cause a stack overflow. What kind of data are you passing to this function?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but `int ps[n][n];` is a stack allocation via VLA (variable-length array).  A static allocation, would actually use the `static` keyword or be a global.  In a static allocation, you cannot use a VLA, as the size would need to be known at compile time.

Comment: As for an answer to your question, it *may* actually have something to do with the way memory becomes "resident."  Memory that is allocated but not written to, may not actually become "resident" and will not count toward your program.  It's possible, `malloc`'s book keeping is writing to pages that might not otherwise have been "commited."  This is a platform specific topic, so your operating system and how you are measuring memory consumption is important information here.

Comment: OT: be aware that `int ps[n][n]` is not at all equivalent to `int *ps = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int))`, with latter `ps` is just a pointer to `int` and you cannot do `ps[x][y]`. With `int ps[n][n]`, `ps` is an n x n array.

Comment: You didn't say how memory usage was being measured, but that's probably where the difference lies, not (very much) in the actual amount of memory used.

Comment: No, @Jason, `(ps[i][j] = (s[i] == s[j]))` evaluates to the result of `ps[i][j] = (s[i] == s[j])`, which is the value assigned, itself the result of `(s[i] == s[j])`.  I see no reason to expect that that would always evaluate to 1.  And if it did, then enclosing the whole thing in an additional set of parentheses would not change that (though it might silence a compiler warning).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I just tried it and you are correct.  Adding parentheses only seems to silence the warning as if to tell the compiler, "No I really did mean that."

Comment: Yes, @Jason, that is exactly the point of the extra parentheses, at least for GCC.  Other compilers might or might not warn about such constructs in the first place, and if they do, they might or might not be silenced by extra parentheses.  The point of such warnings, is to try to detect cases where the programmer meant `==` but mistakenly wrote `=` instead.  That does not appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating `ps` on the stack. If that actually works in leetcode, then apparently leetcode is both permitting this with its own very large stack allocation in order to not crash, and that leetcode is not counting it as memory usage. In short, it appears that you are tricking leetcode in a way that it should not allow. 244 MB is an outrageous stack size. A typical default stack size for C compilers is 8 MB.